# Show data from specific table in my view django

Tags: django

I want only the requests from the Hospital.
How can I achieve this?

Example:

> User from Hospital

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
FKbelongs_to = models.ForeignKey('HospitalViewRoleForUsers', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

> Hospital Model

```
 class HospitalViewRoleForUsers(models.Model):
     RequestsFromLab = models.ForeignKey('request', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

> Requests from the Hospital

```
FKHospitalRequests = models.ForeignKey('HospitalViewRoleForUsers', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    user_request = models.ForeignKey('customuser', on_delete= models.PROTECT)
```

In my View I need to validate which Hospital the user belongs to and,
Pass only the request information from that hospital to my user view.

> The user view that I am trying to build

```
def Get_UserRequestByHospital(request, pk):
user = request.user
items = requests.objects.filter(FKHospitalRequests = 1).values_list('id', flat = True)
return render(request, 'user_profile/list-user-request.html', {'items': items})
```

> In Jupyter testing data it appears like this

```
    user_hospital2 = requests.objects.filter(FKHospitalRequests = 1).values_list('id', flat = True)
<QuerySet [1]>
```

As we can see, Jupyter returns the request id. Which is linked to the Hospital. But, I am confused and I need help thinking on a solution. I am new to Django, so. I suppose I need to pass the PK to the view, and then, create a filter to check if PK is equal to FK from the Hospital Request? But, also, How I know this user belongs to the Hospital? Thank you. I am really lost and I am new to Django.

-- Edit: Users from the same hospital can see others users requests.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by doing this:

In my view of requests I added a FK to check if is equal to the User FK.
With this method I can make only users from Hospital 1, to see the requests of Hospital 1.

```
def Get_UserRequest(request, FKbelongs_to_id):
    user = request.user 
    if CustomUser.objects.filter(FKbelongs_to_id = FKbelongs_to_id):
        items = requests.objects.filter(FKHospitalRequests_id = FKbelongs_to_id)

    else:

        return HttpResponseNotAllowed("Not Allowed")
```